# 2008 ford explorer ac fast cycles

Tags: ford, ac, explorer

I have a 2008 ford explorer Eddie baur edition 4.0, the ac works awesome for about 20 to 30 minutes, then t will start rapid cycling, new compressor, new accumulator, new orifice tube, full charge, pulled vacuum before charging system, bypassed low pressure switch no change, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the cabin air temperature sensor?

Comment: Usually a fast cycle is a sign the charge is low.

Comment: There may be electronics used to detect excessive low or high pressures to create fast cycling of your Explorer. What was the reason for parts replacement and did anyone perform a leak test using a uv blacklight to find dye? If uv light wasn't used everywhere, there may be a leak not found yet and causing the short cycling. The opposite might be overcharging the system with more refrigerant than specified in labeling found in the engine bay.

Comment: reason for new parts was compressor was shot, leak test has been done twice, ac pressure stays consistent, have not checked temp sensor as of yet,